# Gap is present in span in Angular but not in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angularjs

There are 2 equivalent component templates one written in AngularJS:

```
<span ng-repeat="status in statusInformation.statusList | filter : whereFilter"
      class="show-on-hover">
    <span class="app-icon app-icon_md soh__trigger"
          ng-class="status.informationType.iconClass"></span>
    <span class="soh__content soh__content_multiline app-text_addition-1" ng-bind="status.message"></span>
</span>
```

And a new one is written in modern Angular:

```
<span *ngFor="let status of statusList" class="show-on-hover">
    <span
        class="app-icon app-icon_md soh__trigger"
        [ngClass]="appealStatusAdditionalInformationTypesMap[status.informationType].iconClass"
    ></span>
    <span class="soh__content soh__content_multiline app-text_addition-1">{{ status.message }}</span>
</span>
```

The difference between the two is that in AngularJS it seems that the main span is bigger leading to having a gap:

[image]

While in modern Angular the same span is smaller, leading to having no gap between the icons:

[image]

The resulting html is as follows (old one with the gap):

```
<appeal-status-information status-information="rowData.appealStatusAdditionalInformation" applicant-type="rowData.applicantInfo.applicantType" class="ng-isolate-scope">
  <!-- ngRepeat: status in statusInformation.statusList | filter : whereFilter -->
  <span ng-repeat="status in statusInformation.statusList | filter : whereFilter" class="show-on-hover ng-scope">
    <span class="app-icon app-icon_md soh__trigger app-icon_cl_prime gis-icon gis-icon-main-response" ng-class="status.informationType.iconClass"></span>
    <span class="soh__content soh__content_multiline app-text_addition-1 ng-binding" ng-bind="status.message">Response received</span>
  </span>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: status in statusInformation.statusList | filter : whereFilter -->
  <span ng-repeat="status in statusInformation.statusList | filter : whereFilter" class="show-on-hover ng-scope">
    <span class="app-icon app-icon_md soh__trigger app-icon_cl_action mdi mdi-20px mdi-thumb-up-outline" ng-class="status.informationType.iconClass"></span>
    <span class="soh__content soh__content_multiline app-text_addition-1 ng-binding" ng-bind="status.message">Appeal status: Information received</span>
  </span>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: status in statusInformation.statusList | filter : whereFilter -->
</appeal-status-information>
```

And the new one without:

```
<appeal-status-information>
  <span class="show-on-hover ng-star-inserted">
    <span class="app-icon app-icon_md soh__trigger app-icon_cl_prime gis-icon gis-icon-main-response"></span>
    <span class="soh__content soh__content_multiline app-text_addition-1">Response received</span>
  </span>
  <span class="show-on-hover ng-star-inserted">
    <span class="app-icon app-icon_md soh__trigger app-icon_cl_action mdi mdi-20px mdi-thumb-up-outline"></span>
    <span class="soh__content soh__content_multiline app-text_addition-1">Appeal status: Information received</span>
  </span>
  <!---->
</appeal-status-information>
```

As you can see, the styles are identical, yet leading to different results.
What's likely the reason of the span in old angular being larger?

Comment: can you check if there are text nodes inside of those spans? `$0.childNodes` and check if there is `text` there